# SSIS 2008 - Truncation Error CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

My SSIS 2008 package is throwing the following error when I try to process my CSV file:

***Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "MYCOLUMNNAME" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".***

When I preview the Flat-File everything looks good (there are only 8 rows) and when I preview the Flat File Source everything looks good (again only 8 rows).  The External Columns and Output Columns of the Flat File Source "Input and Output" properties both show the column as a four-byte signed integer [DT_I4].

The Output Column is also set for TruncationRowDisposition as RD_IgnoreFailure.  I also have Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow checked.  I get the error whether ValidateExternalMetadata is set to True or False.

The process fails on the Flat File Source step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A blank row at the end of your csv file can generate this error.  Make sure there are no blank rows in the file.

Comment: In the preview there are no blank rows though.